# preg_match_all in php to capture specific text for a specific parent tag

Tags: php

The text that I need to parse is

```
<td width="35%"><small>Bourke AP AWS</td> <!--$94703-->
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center"><small>ESE  13</small></td>
  <td align="right"><small> 21</small></td>
  <td align="right"><small> 16</small></td>
  <td align="right"><small> 21</small>
```

I need to be able to extract the number "21" before the final `</small>` tag, but I also need to the code to only get me this number for unique places in the page, for instance, either for the name "Bourke AP AWS" or for "" which are unique identifiers to weather observation sites.  The page has many other chunks of text as above, the only thing differentiating them being either the name or the commented out station number.

My code

```
preg_match_all('/<td width="35%"><small>Bourke AP AWS<\/td>(.*?).*?<td>([^<]+)<\/td>.*?<td align="center"><small>(.*?)<\/small><\/td>.*?<td align="center"><small>(.*?)<\/small><\/td>.*?<td align="right"><small>(.*?)<\/small><\/td>.*?<td align="right"><small>(.*?)<\/small><\/td>.*?<td align="right"><small>(.*?)<\/small>/s', $datamaxtemp, $matchnewtemp, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$ymaxtemppmq = strip_tags($matchnewtemp[0][0]);
```

returns nothing when I try to echo out $ymaxtemppmq from above.  My understanding is that it should give me the first captured text (in this case ), but that does not seem to be the case.

Any help in this case will be highly appreciated.

Comment: don't parse xml with `preg_match ...` functions. Use xml parsers

Comment: Please post a **clear** sample of the **input** and desired **output**

Comment: So, a preg_match_all on your requirement may be possible, but I'm not sure about the performance of this. I tried can't do it. I purpose you this : https://regex101.com/r/MRDgij/1

Then after, you foreach $matchnewtemp and add each key in an array (the key that have for value 21)

Comment: Thanks, everyone for taking a look into this.  The input is as above, the desired output is the number "21".  I will leave the question open; hopefully someone will spot the mistake I am making in the way I am writing the preg_match_all function out.

Comment: The mistake is using a regex to begin with. In this particular example, there are errors in the HTML, so a regex will quickly lose the way. Use a HTML parser (not an XML one, on account of the error) and retrieve the content from the last node.

Comment: Thank you all. The mistake is in using regex to parse the html, indeed.  I've finally managed to solve the above problem using the inbuilt php dom parser. This thread can be closed now.

Comment: @Mohammed You can close the post yourself.